# Using Spies and Mocks on complex objects with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom, mocking, jestjs

I'm fairly new to testing and writing tests for a currently uncovered javaScript codebase using Jest. The code covers some niche use cases, as its conditionally injected and executed by the browser during page load. Anyway, I'm having issues mocking up custom objects. Here's the function in question:

```
const setEnterpriseCookie = () => {
        // Get the current page uri
        let path = window.location.pathname;

        // Matches all pages containing '/regex_expression'
        if (path.match(/.*\/regex_expression.*/)) {
            window.TOOL.cookie.setCookie(...args);
        }
    };
```

As far as I understand, I need to mock both `window.location.pathname` to return a string, and I need to mock `window.TOOL.cookie.setCookie()` as a mock function. Here's my attempt at the test:

```
var windowSpy;

describe('Tests for the page-specific-methods.js file', () => {

    beforeEach( () => {
        windowSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'window', 'get');
    });

    afterEach( () => {
        windowSpy.mockRestore();
    })

    test('Test the page path detecting the enterprise string', () => {
        windowSpy.mockImplementation( () => ({
            location: {
                pathname: '/enterprise/contact',
            },
            TOOL: {
                cookie: {
                    setCookie: jest.fn(),
                },
            },
        }));

        setEnterpriseCookie();
        
        expect(window.TOOL.cookie.setCookie).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(window.TOOL.cookie.setCookie).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(...args);
    })
});
```

The test fails, saying that `window.TOOL.cookie.setCookie` was called 0 times. I've dug into the process, and found that `window.location.pathname` is executing as expected, and thus the code is entering the conditional that calls `window.TOOL.cookie.setCookie`. I think the problem is somewhere in how I'm mocking `window.TOOL.cookie.setCookie`, but I haven't been able to find any help that describes how to mock methods so many .'s deep.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `window` is read-only in JSDOM, so is `location`, as it's expected from real DOM. You need to mock one level higher, `TOOL`. Or disable Jest JSDOM for this test suite and set up `window` the way you need to make it pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) defines property directly on `window` object.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
const setEnterpriseCookie = (...args) => {
  let path = window.location.pathname;
  if (path.match(/.*\/enterprise.*/)) {
    window.TOOL.cookie.setCookie(...args);
  }
};

exports.setEnterpriseCookie = setEnterpriseCookie;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const { setEnterpriseCookie } = require('./');

describe('63274598', () => {
  describe('Tests for the page-specific-methods.js file', () => {
    test('Test the page path detecting the enterprise string', () => {
      Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
        value: { pathname: '/enterprise/contact' },
      });
      Object.defineProperty(window, 'TOOL', {
        value: {
          cookie: {
            setCookie: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
      });
      setEnterpriseCookie('123');

      expect(window.TOOL.cookie.setCookie).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(window.TOOL.cookie.setCookie).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('123');
    });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/63274598/index.test.js (13.923s)
  63274598
    Tests for the page-specific-methods.js file
      ✓ Test the page path detecting the enterprise string (4ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 3                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.975s
```

Comment: This works. I'll add the note here that for future test cases, the `window.TOOL.cookie.setCookie` needs to be cleared for this to be reusable. I added

```javascript
afterEach( () => {
    window.TOOL.cookie.setCookie.mockClear();
});
```
and now its reusable!